# WordPress User Roles, Custom Post Types, and Admin views

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, admin

My friend mentioned that there is a simple way to modify what users see in the admin sidebar based on their user role. I have a large number of custom post types, one for each user, and I need to limit these users (currently given the role 'author') access to only their own post type and the Posts (not even Pages). I also want to hide Widgets from them. Is there a bit of PHP I can stick in my functions.php file to accomplish this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone else having the same problem as me, I used the [Role Scoper plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/), which is recommended by WordPress on their page that describes user roles. It has a very simple UI, and is easy to install and use.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you for what you are looking for.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this is close but doesn't quite do what I wanted it to do.